# Zariski-homeomorphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology

This question is motivated by two questions [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78771/is-mathbbc2-homeomorphic-to-mathbbc2-0-0-with-the-zariski-topolo) and 
[at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514578/what-is-the-homotopy-type-of-the-affine-space-in-the-zariski-topology/684947#684947).

I am interested in homeomorphism types of (irreducible) complex-projective varieties with respect to the Zariski topology. Any two Zariski-homeomorphic varieties have to have the same dimension, but there are more subtle Zariski-topological invariants as well. Examples of Zariski-homeomorphisms are provided by biregular maps between  varieties and the action of the Galois group $Gal({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb Q})$. Furthermore, clearly, any bijection between (irreducible) projective curves is a Zariski-homeomorphism. On the other hand, it appears that the extreme flexibility of Zariski topology in dimension 1 is just an accident. For instance, it is not hard to prove (and it was essentially known in the 19th century) that the only Zariski-homeomorphisms ${\mathbb C}P^n\to {\mathbb C}P^n$ ($n\ge 2$) are compositions of projective transformations and elements of $Gal({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb Q})$.

**Question 1.** Suppose that $X, Y$ are (irreducible) complex-projective varieties of dimension $\ge 2$. Is it true that the set of Zariski-homeomorphisms $X\to Y$ is obtained by composing biregular maps (not necessarily between $X$ and $Y$) with actions of some elements of $Gal({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb Q})$?

**Question 2.** (Somewhat weaker.) Suppose that $X, Y$ are Zariski-homeomorphic (irreducible) complex-projective varieties of dimension $\ge 2$. Is it true that there exists a Zariski-homeomorphism  $X\to Y$ obtained by composing a biregular map $X'\to Y'$ with actions of some elements of $Gal({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb Q})$?

Comment: The following papers may be relevant to your question: 
Hrushovski, Zilber, *Zariski geometries*, Bullettins of the AMS (1993); Hrushovski, Zilber, *Zariski geometries*, Journal of the AMS (1996); Zilber, *Zariski geometries: geometry from the logician's point of view* (2009).

Comment: @Qfwfq: Thank you, I will take a look!

Comment: Since your question was asked, there has been some progress on the Zariski reconstruction problem. However I don't know enough algebraic geometry to understand if this answers your question. https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.04847

Comment: @IanAgol: Thank you, I will take a look!